# Dynamic DataGridView creation columns and rows not coming in winform using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i am trying to create a 8*8 gridview but the columns & rows aren't coming .. my code is like this ..

```
 public static DataGridView[] grid = new DataGridView[30];
 public DataGridViewImageColumn col;

grid[i] = new DataGridView();
            grid[i].Visible = true;
            grid[i].AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            grid[i].AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            grid[i].AllowUserToOrderColumns = false;
            grid[i].AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
            grid[i].AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
            grid[i].ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
            grid[i].RowHeadersVisible = false;
            grid[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(120,5);
            grid[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(128, 128);
            grid[i].BackgroundColor = Color.SeaShell;
            grid[i].GridColor = Color.Green;
            grid[i].ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithoutHeaderText;
            grid[i].CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.Single;
            for (j = 1; j <= 8; j++)
            {
                col = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
                col.Width = 2;
                col.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Normal;
                grid[i].Columns.Add(col);
            }
            for (k = 1; k <= 8; k++)
            {
                grid[i].Rows.Add();
            }

            epnl[i].Controls.Add(grid[i]);
```

here epnl is a panel. i am trying to set the height of every cell as 2 and width as 2 as well but the cells are not coming .. i am only getting an empty datagridview pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically because your not adding anything.

You need to create Row object :-

```
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();

for (k = 1; k <= 8; k++)
            {
                grid[i].Rows.Add(row);
            }
```

I think this should help.

Comment: this will give me exception on the line `grid[i].Rows.Add(row);`